# RStudio: how to set the Git executable in Windows 7?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise on a work laptop.

I downloaded the GitHub Desktop app from the GitHub site  (https://desktop.github.com/) and installed it. I read somewhere that the GitHub Desktop app automatically installs Git. I verified version control is working OK using both the GitHub Desktop app and also using the command line in shell.

But now I want to use Git with my RStudio app. SO I went to Tools | Global Options, clicked on the Git/SVN item on the left panel. The second item in the dialog asks for "Git executable".  I looked in all the usual places like:

```
C:\Program Files
C:\users\<my_name>\AppData\Local\GitHub
```

but cannot see where the Git executable is.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look deeper into your `AppData\Local\GitHub` folder. I found mine in `AppData\Local\GitHub\Portable_Git_XXXXXX\bin\git.exe` where `XXXX` is a string of 32 characters or so.

Comment: Thanks. This was the correct answer. Interestingly, I could not see the AppData folder when looking inside the RStudio dialog, and yet I can see it when I navigate to  C:\users\<my_name>\  in Windows.Since this is a work laptop, I'm not sure if this is due to corporate security settings on the laptop, or whether its a bug or feature of RStudio. Anyway, I overcame it by typing in the entire path to the Git.exe executable, as follows:  C:\Users\<my_name>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_XXXXXX\bin\git.exe